# Error while configuring data source setting in Jet report?

Tags: sql-server, report, jet, dsn, navision

I have configured the Jet report with Excel 2013 and trying to connect with data source using Data source setting. I have NAV 2016 installed on my system. After giving **Server** and **Server type**, It is showing the correct list of databases available on server. But when I am testing the connection it is showing the below error:[image]

I am new to it. Can anyone guide me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed C/Front?

Comment: No, from where to install it? any link  to download that?

Comment: It's part of the NAV SDK

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jet Reports you are installing? Have you tried same thing on latest version of it? As we faced the kind of issue and when we downloaded the latest version and done, it worked.